# HP P4000 LeftHand SRA for SRM will not install on vSphere 5.1

Tags: lefthand, vmware-srm

I'm attempting to install the HP LeftHand P4000 Storage Replication Adapter in VMWare Site Recovery Manager 5.1 with vSphere 5.1

However, the LeftHand SRA keeps stating that SRM is not installed, even when it is.

[image: The VMware Site Recovery Manager must be installed before the HP P4000 SRA for VMware SRM 5 can be installed.]

Is there any way I can convince it that it is installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The problem is that the SRA installer is looking in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\VMware, Inc.\VMware vCenter Site Recovery Manager` for its registry keys, but that's not where they are in 5.1 - they are just in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware vCenter Site Recovery Manager`:

[image]

This is an easy fix. Export `HKLM\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware vCenter Site Recovery Manager` from the above registry key on your SRM server, open the `.reg` file in notepad, add the `\Wow6432Node\` into the path, and then re-import it.

Voila, an exact duplicate of your registry entries in the correct place. Now you can install:

[image]

Yay!

[image]

If you continue to have issues, [please refer to Dave's additional answer below](https://serverfault.com/a/435974/7709).

Answer (score 3):

The above is not complete, though it set me on the correct path, there were more keys that the SRA was looking for.  I had to add a few keys to get this to work:  below is what you will need.  Tested this a couple of different ways and this worked:  add the following entries to the registry and it should work:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.\VMware vCenter Site Recovery Manager]
"InstallPath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VMware\\Infrastructure\\Virtual Infrastructure Client\\Plugins\\VMware vCenter Site Recovery Manager\\"
"InstalledVersion"="5.1.0.3885"
```

Create a .reg file from the above, copy and paste this, then import and you should be fine.  Again, deleted all the keys, did them one-by-one and tried again to find valid configuration.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I didn't have this particular issue myself, but thanks for making us aware.